# Can I install the latest Windows 11 apps on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, notepad, microsoft-paint, snipping-tool

There are a lot of apps updated with Windows 11 which includes Microsoft Store, Photos, Notepad, MS-Paint, Snipping tool, Snip n Sketch, etc. They all are available at windows 11 but not at Windows 10. Microsoft Store is available and Photos(maybe), but not others. Is there a way I can install any of the new app that came with windows 11 on Windows 10? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Windows 11 is experimenting with Tabs for File Explorer, Notepad and other apps.

This can be seen in Windows 11 Insider (I have this running) and will come to Windows 11 Production at some point (I have Windows 11 Production running).

So the pool of Windows Apps is / will be different from Windows 10 and so far as I know will not be back filled to Windows 10.

Remember that Windows 11 is a very different operating system compared to Windows 10 for Microsoft apps and user interface.

**So to your question: *Can I install the latest Windows 11 apps on Windows 10?***

No, generally not practical. If you want / need these newer apps, upgrade to Windows 11.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your advice, I really love windows 11, specially its MS-Paint and Notepad app, but my PC doesn't support Windows 11.